# Set default date and time for using jquery.datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using jquery.datetimepicker.js for my date field. I have following code that allows user to select date and time. I also want to set a default date and time. I tried few things but did not work.

```
$("#dateId").datetimepicker({ 
    format: 'm/d/Y  g:i A'  ,
    step:1       
});
```

Please help

Comment: You want the field to be populated automatically with a default date and time?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change straight forward the default input value of datepicker : **datetimepicker-input**. See here http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/8h2eLo1f/ .

So, your code could be:

```
var d = new Date();
var month = 6 ; //Now d.getMonth()+1;
var day = 10 ; //Now d.getDate();

var output =  (month<10 ? '0' : '')+month+ '/' +
 (day<10 ? '0' : '')+ day + '/' +
 + d.getFullYear();

$("#datetimepicker-input").val(output + " 03:11:20");

$('#dateId').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you meant by accepting the answer. Please explain.

Comment: Accept the answer by pressing the tick near the answer to thank me!